# Firemonkey application - launch external app when running under OS X

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

I have a Firemonkey app (Delphi Berlin 10.1) and wish to launch an external program from it.  (The external program is a helpfile viewer.)

When I am compiling for Win32, I can simply do this (when the external program is in the same folder as the main executable):

```
path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
path := path + 'MyViewer.exe';
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PWideChar(path), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

When I'm compiling for OS X, I have the Mac version of the external program, MyViewer.app. Where do I place it? How do I get it into the bundle created by PAServer? What code is required to launch it?

Comment: Watch out! ShellExecute works on windows but not on OS X, they don't have the same set of system calls. OS X should have "open"

Comment: @AlbertoMiola Perhaps my question was not clear. I was asking for help on two issues. (1) How to launch an OS X app from my Firemonkey app? (2) How to deploy the OS X app with my Firemonkey app?

Answer (score 3):

1. This shows the equivilent for Windows and OSX:

   ```
   uses
   {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
   winapi.shellapi
   {$ENDIF}
   {$IFDEF POSIX}
   Posix.Stdlib
   {$ENDIF POSIX}
   ;

   function ExecuteFile(const filename, Params, DefaultDir: string;
         ShowCmd: integer): THandle;
     begin
       {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
         result := ShellExecute(0, 'Open', PChar(filename), PChar(Params),
           PChar(DefaultDir), ShowCmd);
       {$ENDIF}
       {$IFDEF MACOS}
         _system(PAnsiChar('open ' + AnsiString(filename)));
       {$ENDIF}
     end;
   ```
2. I have done this by putting another signed bundle anywhere inside the first bundle after the first bundle is made. I think you can get the other app into the bundle by using the Deploy page in Delphi by just putting the other executable (not the bundle) it in the same place as Delphi puts the main app code.

Comment: Thanks for helpful suggestion. Using your code, I was able to successfully launch the secondary app (let's call it MyViewer.app) by manually placing its bundle at '/Users/[username]/PAServer/scratch-dir/[profile]/MyViewer.app'. Your suggestion of putting the secondary app's executable (not its bundle) into Delphi's OSX32/Debug directory did not work for me as Delphi didn't seem to deploy it to the Mac.

Comment: Effectively, I have two Mac OS apps to deploy - the one I wrote myself in Firemonkey and another written by others that I have as a separate bundle. I haven't figured out to how deploy the second from the IDE when testing via Paserver. However, all works if I package both apps up into a .pkg using the "Packages" software http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

Comment: When running the FMX Mac app from the IDE via Paserver, the secondary app (the one to be started by the main app) should be added to the deployment manager with its Remote Path set to "Contents\MacOS".  Then the secondary app will be in the correct place to be started by the main app.

Comment: Hi: I need to open "VLC" with a videofile and subtitle file as flag parameters. I´ve concatenated the params after the app pah, with the path to the files and the application, enclausurated with single " ' ". Didn´t work, The app is not launched and no message shows. I also saved the command string on a text file in order to test if the problem is the command syntax, but the output of the text file worked by running directly on a command window. Is there another method that can be called that as on Windows.ShellExecute, has a "param" parameter? Is this aproach apropriate?